# Change DateTime Format {"MM/dd/yyyy"} to {"dd/MM/yyyy"} and time should remain same in Unity

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

I want to change DateTime now to the Format {"MM/dd/yyyy"} using this code.

```
string.Format("{0:MM:dd:yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
```

and saving it.

after getting saved string I get DateTime in format {"MM/dd/yyyy"} . Now I want to convert it in another format so I can Parse to DateTime. when I try to parse MM/dd/yyyy to DateTime got an error

> "FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is this specific to C# ? If so, please add the tag for findability of the question.

Comment: Please add a language tag. But be aware, in most languages with an explicit type representing a `datetime` value, it doesn't *have* a format, being a simple count of intervals since some epoch. Formats only become relevant when converting to or from some strings.

Comment: Why format a datetime as a string and save the string value? Just save the DateTime natively and format when needed - no need to parse at all.

Comment: there is a requirement to save as MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 3):

You can rather use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) which allows you to specify the exact date format you are expeting the input to have.

For example

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
Debug.Log(now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    
var example1 = now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
Debug.Log(example1);
    
var readTime1 = DateTime.ParseExact(example1, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Debug.Log(readTime1.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    
var example2 = now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
Debug.Log(example2);
    
var readTime2 = DateTime.ParseExact(example2, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Debug.Log(readTime2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
```

See [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IKqdBh)

Answer (score 0):

The format is only relevant for display

If you save it in a C# DateTime variable, there is no "format" when saving it, this DateTime is a struct data type which is universal and not bound to any specific format

If you want to use a specific format for parsing, you can use:

```
// Parse date and time with custom specifier.

CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00";   

format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";

DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

You can use CultureInfo to optimize your format for you needs

If there is a need to save it as "MM/dd/yyyy", your should save it as string

best regards